# Can't use a list produced by a function in a future function

Tags: python

This might be a pretty simple question but I'm new to Python and to programming in general. I want to use a list that is produced by a function as a parameter in another function, like so:

```
def grades():
    my_list = []
    i = 1
    for i in range(1, 6):
        grade = float(input("Insert the student's grade: "))
        my_list.append(grade)
    return my_list


def average(my_list):
    avrg = sum(my_list) / len(my_list)
    return "The average of the students' grades is : " + str(avrg)


grades()
average(my_list)
```

It won't let me use my_list as a parameter in the second function. Also, if I make it global I can't use it as a parameter anymore. Except if I'm doing it wrong and there's an another way to do it. What I basically want, is for a function to create a list based on the user's input and for that list to be used by another function to find the average of the numbers in the list.

Comment: you should return your value: `my_list = grades()`, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-we-return-a-list-from-a-Python-function

Comment: Note that something called `x` in one scope is not thereby related to something with the same name in a different scope. Even separate calls of a function use the same names, but the values they represent are not necessarily the same.

Comment: `return` statements do not create variable bindings in the calling scope; they simply set the *value* of a function-call expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared inside functions are intentionally only in the scope of that function, and functions declared within it. If you want to use a value from inside the function, the most common way is to return the value and assign it. For example:

```
def grades():
    my_list = []
    i = 1
    for i in range(1, 6):
        grade = float(input("Insert the student's grade: "))
        my_list.append(grade)
    return my_list


def average(my_list):
    avrg = sum(my_list) / len(my_list)
    return "The average of the students' grades is : " + str(avrg)


grades = grades()
output = average(grades)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like:

```
def grades():
    my_list = []
    i = 1
    for i in range(1, 6):
        grade = float(input("Insert the student's grade: "))
        my_list.append(grade)
    return my_list


def average(my_list):
    avrg = sum(my_list) / len(my_list)
    return "The average of the students' grades is : " + str(avrg)


print(average(grades()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling grades() without assigning the output to a variable.  In your example that should be my_list.  So change your code to:

```
my_list = grades()
average(my_list)
```